# getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream() is returning Null with Java 12

Tags: java, getresource, getresponsestream

I am working on Java upgrade of my spring boot application in IntelliJ. I am upgrading an application from Java 8 to Java 12. The application consists of tests, in which one test checks for file existence and get its content. Below is the code :

```
String fileName = "myFile.txt"; 
InputStream stream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
```

This file exists at path: **src\test\resources\myFile.txt**

But it always returning null.

I have tried these lines but nothing worked :

- MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
- getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename)
- getClass().getResource(filename)
- getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(filename)
- getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("\src\test\resources\myFile.txt")

How to get the result with the latest Java?

Comment: Where you stored myFile.txt file? could you please share the path?

Comment: I have written in question, the file exists at path : src\test\resources\myFile.txt

Comment: Have you double checked that your artifact contains the file at the expected path?

Comment: @JulianDurchholz yes it exists.

Comment: try adding the test resource path to the classpath.

Comment: No it doesn't exist at the expected path, otherwise it would have been found. The expected path is the root of the package hierarchy.

Comment: @KusalHettiarachchi it added, it was working fine with old java 8.